# Strange line-height in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm experiencing a big problem with line height and block height which is a multiplicity of it. I have font-size of 15px, line height 1.5em (22.5px) and div height of: 16 lines * 1.5em = 24 em. It looks well in Firefox and MS Edge - div contains only 16 lines, as expected. But in Chrome actual text height becomes a bit smaller! And it shows also the parts of 17th line in blocks. Looks very weird.

Why does it happen and how to fix it with CSS?

```css
.post-preview_main__content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 24em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  width: 420px;
  overflow: hidden
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-preview_main__content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, necessitatibus, quidem in beatae quae quo perspiciatis nihil adipisci aut fuga ad possimus illo nisi vitae libero debitis accusantium magni esse. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Culpa, natus, deleniti tenetur quos hic voluptate itaque nobis</p>

  <p>cum magni magnam ipsa enim a labore maxime repellendus eaque exercitationem nihil doloribus! ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, aliquam voluptate atque ipsa eveniet tempore sed cumque non magnam accusamus enim consectetur fuga
    fugiat ducimus dolorum temporibus dolor facilis doloribus. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quisquam, vel dignissimos natus porro veniam velit quia odit quam dolorum reprehenderit vero eos modi non ea voluptate eligendi
    consectetur officia.</p>

  <p> cum magni magnam ipsa enim a labore maxime repellendus eaque exercitationem nihil doloribus! ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, aliquam voluptate atque ipsa eveniet tempore sed cumque non magnam accusamus enim consectetur fuga
    fugiat ducimus dolorum temporibus dolor facilis doloribus. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quisquam, vel dignissimos natus porro veniam velit quia odit quam dolorum reprehenderit vero eos modi non ea voluptate eligendi
    consectetur officia.</p>

  <p>cum magni magnam ipsa enim a labore maxime repellendus eaque exercitationem nihil doloribus! ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, aliquam voluptate atque ipsa eveniet tempore sed cumque non magnam accusamus enim consectetur fuga
    fugiat ducimus dolorum temporibus dolor facilis doloribus. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quisquam, vel dignissimos natus porro veniam velit quia odit quam dolorum reprehenderit vero eos modi non ea voluptate eligendi
    consectetur officia.</p>

  <p>cum magni magnam ipsa enim a labore maxime repellendus eaque exercitationem nihil doloribus! ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, aliquam voluptate atque ipsa eveniet tempore sed cumque non magnam accusamus enim consectetur fuga
    fugiat ducimus dolorum temporibus dolor facilis doloribus. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quisquam, vel dignissimos natus porro veniam velit quia odit quam dolorum reprehenderit vero eos modi non ea voluptate eligendi
    consectetur officia.</p>
</div>
```

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Comment: i don't think there is issue. You have set 15px and line-height 1.5em and taking line-height 22.5px as you want. Its ok i think

i have checked on chrome too :)

Comment: Div height is 24em and must contain 24 / 1.5 - only 16 lines, but it contains also the part of 17th, don't you see?

Comment: ummm i see
yea you are right

Comment: Could you also provide a screenshot from a browser where it is displayed correctly (and highlight the issues in the other screenshot)? I can't see the issue at the moment...

Comment: What zoom level have you got set in Chrome? If it's not 100%, does it still happen if you set the zoom level to 100%

Comment: 100% of course. I figured out that the problem is in a fractional value of line-height - 22.5px , webkit doesn't handle this right. But how can I keep line height always integer while font-size changes when user scales the page??

Comment: Very strange issue indeed. Maybe it is a bug in Chrome, have you tried to report it to the development team? (In the Chrome help menu there is a menu item "Report an issue...") I did that once when I found a C# compiler bug in VS, the Roslyn team was quite responsive and quickly fixed it. Not sure how fast and responsive the Chrome team is, but is worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that the problem is in a fractional value of line-height - 22.5px (15px*1.5), WebKit doesn't handle this right, and this is its great disadvantage. 
The problem is that even if I change line-height to give me integer px value, I can't keep it integer while font-size changes when user scales the page.